# sharing a folder of content between plone lineage subsites

Tags: plone

I have collective.lineage installed. I have /site1 as a subsite and I have /sharedfolder as a folder with content in my root site. I want to make this folder visible within site1 (or site2 as well). I can create a link which in my subsite to sharedfolder, which is /site1/sharedfolder. This works however the top level navigation and the breadcrumbs reflect the root site not the subsite.
Is there another way to share this content or is this a bug?

Comment: This is the intended behaviour not a bug. Can you give more info about the usecase? Spontaneously I'd say, make the sharedfolder a subsite, too, would make sense, in case you never want users to see the actual siteroot.

Comment: We never want users to see the root site. We just want sharefolder to be as if it's in both sites.

Comment: Are you sure it's expected behaviour? I know that acquisition should mean the acquired item will retain the security context of where it actually live but I'm not sure that globalnav and the navigation portlets should be designed to work this way?

Comment: lineage gives an object an own navigation-root so yes, this is the expected behaviour. don't have a quick solution about the sharedfolder should appear like being in site1, respectively site2. You'd have to check from where the user clicked the link to make a destinction and adjust the sharedfolder's appearance accordingly. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution:

- Use adi.dropdownmenu (disclaimer: I am the author) for the mainmenu on top, assign two dropdownmenus ('Navigation extended') on the sharefolder, one mirroring the folder-structure of site1 and one for site2.
- Assign users of site1 to group1 and users of site2 to group2 and apply two stylesheets that by condition are only delivered to members of group1, respectively group2. Stylesheet1  should hide menu2 and vice versa.

EDIT: Instead for using a groupmembership as condition for the stylesheets you can also distinct where the user came from, f.e. like this:

```
python: context.REQUEST.get('HTTP_REFERER').contains('idOfSite1')
```